# Show QWidget with QSlider on top of tray icon

Tags: qt, position, qwidget, trayicon, qslider

I'm trying to implement some kind of volume slider in Qt.
I have added the `QWidget` with a `QSlider` on it. It works
fine for me... But! `QWidget` shows on the screen center.
But I need it on top of the tray icon.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Code:

```
VolumeSlider::VolumSlider(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);
    resize(20, 150);

    slider = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical, this);
    slider->setRange(0, 100);
    slider->setSingleStep(5);
    slider->setPageStep(10);
    slider->setValue(currentVolume);
    slider->resize(20, 150);
}
```

I'm showing the `QWidget` witha `QSlider` on middle click:

```
connect(trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),
  this, SLOT(trayIconClicked(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
```

And a slot implementation is:

```
void VolumeSlider::trayIconClicked(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    if (reason == QSystemTrayIcon::MiddleClick) {
        show();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your attention!

Best regards!

Comment: You can `move()` widget to `Cursor::pos()` position before showing. (Position should be adjusted on size of widget). If you need more general solution - create menu for your tray icon and fill it with `QWidgetAction` item.

Comment: Actually I'm already have the menu. It appears on mouse right click. But now I need to add the slider popup for mouse middle click. And thanks for the `move` to `Cursor::pos()` advice.

Comment: @ddmytrenko Hi, i'm having the same problem (i'm using PyQt5), did you find a solution to your problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the `QSystemTrayIcon` Class:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html

And this example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-desktop-systray-example.html